# nginx returning 404 after rewriting to url that exists

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I've been banging my head on this one for a while, but could someone please help me figure out why this in my `location /` block isn't matching `http://chrisbenard.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/chromeosalbum.png`?

It's matching and redirecting `http://chrisbenard.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/` to `http://chrisbenard.net/assets/uploads/2010/12/`.

The file [chromeosalbum.png](http://chrisbenard.net/assets/uploads/2010/12/chromeosalbum.png) is obviously in the correct directory. This problem extends to all files under that directory.

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
  rewrite ^/wp\-content/uploads/(.+)? /assets/uploads/$1 permanent;
}
```

Additionally, I'd like `/?s=query` to go to `/search/#?query=query`. I tried:

```
rewrite ^/\?s\=(.*)$ /search/#?query=$1;
```

That one isn't doing the trick either. All of my other regex replacements are working fine. I've migrated from a wordpress install to PieCrust, which is why I need to do all these redirects.

I've tried the first regex with `(.*)`, `(.*)?`, `(.+)`, and a few other variations. I've even tried replacing the `wp\-content` with `.*content` thinking maybe the escape is messed up somehow. I've had no luck.

**Edit:** Also, this same regex worked fine in Apache (for the assets directory; I was unable to get the search regex working). I was using this:

```
RewriteBase /
...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^wp\-content/uploads/(.*)? /assets/uploads/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

There is no leading lash in the apache version because it's not included in the beginning of the string like it is in nginx. Again, all the other nginx rules are working fine with the exception of these 2.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 2:** It turns out that it only happens when the destination of the rewrite exists.

For example, this redirects to the right url:
http://chrisbenard.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/garbage.file.png

This does not redirect to the right url and just returns a 404 (but if you change wp-content to assets, it will load fine):
http://chrisbenard.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/chromeosalbum.png

Comment: I think you need to remove hyphen from `wp\-content`. I have just tried it with alias and it works for me: `location ~ ^/wp-content/uploads/(.*) { alias /your/absolute/path/here/assets/uploads/$1; }`. You better avoid testing if file exists for better performance. Or try this: `location ~ ^/wp-content/uploads/(.*) { rewrite ^/wp-content/uploads/(.+) /assets/uploads/$1 permanent; }`

Comment: I don't want to alias because I want a permanent redirect. The second one may work, but that doesn't let me combine the header setting for images with the rewrite. I had to duplicate the rules (or I guess just move them) as I posted in the answer below. SO won't let me accept my answer for 2 days.

Comment: You can use `add_header` straight in `location` block.

Comment: Basically the problem is that I can't specify that the `location` block is only for files that exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block is matching and interfering:

```
location ~* \.(?:ico|svg|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    expires 3d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

Even when I made it this, I still had a problem:

```
location ~* \.(?:ico|svg|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    if (-e $request_filename) {
        expires 3d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
}
```

I eventually just duplicated some of my rewrite rules in the location that is matching and it works, but I don't understand why. I guess it's just the most specific match and so it ignores the rules in `location /`.

```
location ~* \.(?:ico|svg|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    if (-e $request_filename) {
        expires 3d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite "^/wp\-content/uploads/(.+)?" /assets/uploads/$1 permanent;
    }
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^/images/(.*)? /assets/images/$1 permanent;
    }
}
```